# Search for parents only (with joins)

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm relatively new to elasticsearch and I'm trying to follow this documentation page:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/parent-join.html

It is mentioned here that a plain `match_all` query will return everything, both the "parents" and the "children" - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/parent-join.html#_searching_with_parent_join .

What isn't mentioned there (maybe because it's basic knowledge) is how do you get the parents only? I simply want to get all the parents, without the children.

How would a query like that look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you have already known the relationship of your join when you do the mappings. Let's use the example from the documentation, you know that the parent will be `question`, and the `answer` will be children. You simply need to query your join field to be `question` only:

```json
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
            "my_join_field": "question"
        }
  },
  "sort": ["my_id"]
}
```

If you use this query, only the documents with `my_join_field` of `question` will be returned (and they are your parent documents). If you want only the children, you could do the same (`my_join_field` will be `answer`).